# jQuery reusable function

Tags: jquery

The following function works well. I would like, however, to reuse the same function by passing new parameters. What is the best way of doing that?

```
function overlay_f (clickable_link, current_link, overlay_content, overlay) {
    var clickable_link = $('.p_wrapper p'),
        overlay = $('#overlay'),
        close_overlay = $('.close_overlay');

    clickable_link.click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        current_link = $(this).attr('class');
        var overlay_content = $('#'+current_link);

        overlay.children().fadeOut(200).promise().done(function () {
            overlay_content.fadeIn();
        });

        overlay.fadeIn();
    });

    overlay.click(function () {
        overlay.fadeOut();
        overlay.children().fadeOut(500);
    });
}    

overlay_f();
```

Comment: Re-use it? You mean make it into a plugin? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Just call the function with different parameters?

Comment: @adeneo That would work if they were actually using the parameters in the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
function overlay_f(cl, o, co) {
    var clickable_link = $(cl),
    overlay = $(o),
    close_overlay = $(co);

    clickable_link.click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();

        current_link = $(this).attr('class');
        var overlay_content = $('#'+current_link);

        overlay.children().fadeOut(200).promise().done(function () {
            overlay_content.fadeIn();
        });
        overlay.fadeIn();
    });

    overlay.click(function(){
        overlay.fadeOut();
        overlay.children().fadeOut(500);
    });
}   

overlay_f('.p_wrapper p', '#overlay', '.close_overlay');
```

Comment: Having said that, this strategy is mostly a hack and you should really be looking at converting this into a plugin as suggested by @jay-blanchard

Comment: OK then I will look into converting it into a plug-in, thanks for your suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Where you're currently just declaring variables with the same names as the parameters (which you never pass arguments to when you call the function), instead check if a value has already been passed, and only initialise to the "default" values if they haven't.

```
function overlay_f(clickable_link, current_link, overlay_content, overlay) {
    var clickable_link = clickable_link || $('.p_wrapper p'),
        overlay = overlay || $('#overlay'),
        close_overlay = $('.close_overlay');

    clickable_link.click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var current_link = current_link || $(this).attr('class'),
            overlay_content = overlay_content || $('#' + current_link);

        overlay.children().fadeOut(200).promise().done(function () {
            overlay_content.fadeIn();
        });
        overlay.fadeIn();
    });

    overlay.click(function () {
        overlay.fadeOut();
        overlay.children().fadeOut(500);
    });
}
```

Then you either call it with no arguments:

```
overlay_f();
```

or pass arguments that are what you want to use inside:

```
overlay_f(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```